# add contact issue in ABNewPersonViewController for iOS 8

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios8

We have developed the application in Xcode 4.6.3 with base SDK 6.1.

I have faced one issue with add contact using ABNewPersonViewController.

when we present ABNewPersonViewController from our application, the first name, last name, company, add photo fields are not visible when ran this application in iOS 8 iPad Device.

This issue will came only in iOS 8 iPad device for both add and edit cases.

Please, help me to get out of this issue. I struggled a lot more days to fix it.

Comment: Can you show some piece of code so we can find out the actual problem?

Comment: ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
 picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
    
 
 UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
 [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];

Comment: Please also share screenshot of output.

Comment: i don't know how to add image in comments block.. i tried to upload inside the question. But it shows error

Comment: edit you question and post over there.

Comment: @abhishekkharwar please check this url for screen shot https://devforums.apple.com/thread/246985

Comment: @abhishekkharwar- did you verify those screen shots from above URL? did you found any solutions...? please let me know.

Comment: It seems very strange problem. Which version of iOS 8 you are using may be problem is in that try to reinstall that iOS.